# Read binary data from PLY file using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, point-clouds

Im trying to read data from this file:

[image: file content]

Which contains both ascii text and float numbers stored in binary. I'm trying to read it by doing the following:

```cpp
        QTextStream in(file);

        QString line;
        line = in.readLine();
        while (!line.startsWith(QString("element vertex"))) {
            line = in.readLine();
        }
        point_count = line.split(QString(" ")).last().toInt();
        qDebug() << "PC: " << point_count;

        while (line != "end_header") {
            line = in.readLine();
        }

        QDataStream* stream = new QDataStream(file);
        stream->skipRawData(in.pos());
        stream->setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);

        float number;
        (*stream) >> number;
        qDebug() << "Float: " << number;
```

But I read -1.98117e+13, which I guess it is wrong, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you inspect the file with a hex editor at the location returned by `in.pos`? Also note that the default byte ordering is big endian; you need to set that to little endian explicitly with `setByteOrder`.

Comment: When you want to read binary data you should *not* use a QTextStream but a QDataStream.

Comment: Thank you so much @Botje ! That was the issue, do you want to write an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Since other people might stumble into this, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default byte order for QDataStream is big endian; change it to little endian:

```
stream->setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian)
```